# configured URL priority: Messaging Service VS phone number settings

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

In twilio's API, you can assign numbers to a messaging service, and you can set incoming/status-callback URLs on both the number and the messaging service. For a number in a messaging service, which URL gets picked if both are set?

Apologies if the documentation lays it out somewhere, I dove through 3 or 4 pages of docs trying to find this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. When a Sender like a phone number is added to a Messaging Service, the Messaging Service will handle the webhooks according to its Integration configuration. You can configure this behavior by going to the **Integration** page of your Messaging Service, and selecting one of the radio buttons under **Incoming Messages**.

[image: Twilio Messaging Service Integration page]

By default, a conversation will be automatically created, and the incoming message webhook configured on the Sender will not be called.

You can configure the webhook to be called for all senders in the Messaging Service by selecting **Send a webhook**.

Select **Defer to sender's webhook** if you want the incoming message webhook of the sender to be triggered.

---

Under the Integration page, there's also a **Delivery Status Callback** field. If you fill out this field, you'll receive webhook requests for the outgoing message delivery status, if you don't provide a status callback URL on the individual message. If a status callback URL is configured on the individual message, only that URL will be triggered.

Here's a sample where the status callback URL is configured on the individual message:

```bash
twilio api:core:messages:create --to +1234567890 `
    --status-callback https://myhost/message-status-callback `
    --messaging-service-sid MG*** `
    --body Ahoy
```

While I have a status callback URL (`https://myhost/messaging-service-status-callback`) configured on the Messaging Service above, it is ignored and `https://myhost/message-status-callback` is called.

When I omit the status callback URL on the message like this:

```bash
twilio api:core:messages:create --to +1234567890  `
    --messaging-service-sid MG*** `
    --body Ahoy
```

The status callback URL on my Messaging Service is called: `https://myhost/messaging-service-status-callback`.

Comment: Thank you, it mostly answered my question. For the outgoing "Delivery Status Callback" -- this can also be set on the sender/incoming_phone_number record, yes? I'd like to verify when/if it is the priority choice. But it's also good to know that the inline `status-callback` API param overrides both (it looks like above).

Comment: There is a **Call status changes** field on the **Voice Configuration** of the sender/incoming_phone_number, the `statusCallback` property in the API.
This is only for status changes related to voice calls, and will not be triggered by messages. There's no message status callback you can configure on the phone number.

Comment: Ah thank you, I had that part confused. Awesome thanks.